# Bootstrap 4-alpha6: Custom File Control Validation Feedback

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have implemented the new custom file control in my forms, and it looks great. Has anyone figured out how (and if) validation feedback can be applied (success, warning, danger states with icon)?

(I wouldn't be surprised or disappointed if it just is not implemented yet, especially since BS4 is still in alpha. I just want to clarify if it is there, and I am just missing it.)

**Point of clarification:** I was referring to this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser. I have been through the documentation many times, but for some reason either I'm missing something, or the custom file control has not been enabled for contextual validation styling?

**Example:**

```
<div class="form-group row has-danger">
  <label for="file1" class=" col-sm-3 col-form-label">File Input</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="custom-file" style="display: block;">
      <input class="custom-file-input" name="file1" type="file">
      <span class="custom-file-control form-control-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <small class="form-control-feedback">The file1 field is required.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does not format as expected, nor does there seem to be any documentation regarding validation formatting options. Here is an image of the result, with the URL field formatting as expected, and the custom file field not:

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that since this question, Bootstrap 4 final is out, and breaking changes were made to both the custom file input and validation classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

For the [file input](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser) you would need additional JS as stated in Docs

> The file input is the most gnarly of the bunch and require additional
>   JavaScript if you’d like to hook them up with functional Choose file…
>   and selected file name text.

---

Basically the same way you would do in V3, adding classes to your elements.

Check the [Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation) for bootstrap V4 alpha

> ### How it works
>
> Here’s a rundown of how they work:
>
> - To use, add `.has-warning`, `.has-danger`, or `.has-success` to the parent element. Any `.col-form-label`, `.form-control`, or custom form
>     element will receive the validation styles.
> - Contextual validation text, in addition to your usual form field help text, can be added with the use of `.form-control-feedback`. This
>     text will adapt to the parent `.has-*` class. By default it only
>     includes a bit of margin for spacing and a modified color for each
>     state.
> - Validation icons are url()s configured via Sass variables that are applied to background-image declarations for each state.
> - You may use your own base64 PNGs or SVGs by updating the Sass variables and recompiling.
> - Icons can also be disabled entirely by setting the variables to none or commenting out the source Sass.

---

See examples on their [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#examples)

**SNIPPET**

```css
.custom-file-control::after {
  content: "Choose file...";
}

.custom-file-control::before {
  content: "Browse";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-warning">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputWarning1">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-warning" id="inputWarning1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Shucks, check the formatting of that and try again.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-danger">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>

<label class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
  <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Hi @dippas, thanks for answering. Unfortunately I didn't phrase the question clearly enough. This is not regarding how to do validation formatting on normal fields, but rather specific to the custom file control. I have updated the question accordingly. Thanks for you thorough response, though. :)

Comment: @mike.bronner for that, you would need additional  JS as stated in the docs `The file input is the most gnarly of the bunch and require additional JavaScript if you’d like to hook them up with functional Choose file… and selected file name text.`

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to reflect that, and I'll mark it as the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation classes to the inputs using JavaScript. The documentation is: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation

In short, the classes you can add are

```
.has-danger

.has-warning

.has-success
```

Comment: Hi John, unfortunately that is not what I was after. I probably did not phrase the question clearly enough. I have updated the question with an example and screenshot.